# Confusion regarding position vectors and movable vectors for gradient of functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have two doubts and any help would be great.

1. Lets say i have a vector [2, 2, 5], this means that this is a position vector (beginning from the origin and 2 units along x, 2 along y and 5 along ) Right?.
   Then if i want to represent a vector between two position vectors then what i would do is i would subtract two positions vectors and this would give rise to a vector X.
   For example: If A = [2, 2, 5] and if B = [3, 2, 5] then A-B = ABvector = [-1, 0, 0] = X
   a) Is this vector X  a position vector with origin at the vector you subtracted from(B) that is (3, 2, 5) form the origin.. or is it a position vector with respect to (0,0,0) origin or is this a 'floating vector' which can be placed anywhere in the space?
   b) If I have a vector [2,2, 5] then it can also be represented as [3, 3, 6] - [1, 1, 1] which looks like difference of two position vectors which should be giving a vector between [3, 3, 6] and [1, 1, 1] which is a floating vector.
   Therefore my main question is how can you identify a position vector and floating vector.
   Here when i use "Floating vector" I mean vector that we can pickup and put it anywhere in the free space.
2. When you say gradient = [f_x, f_y] for z =f(x, y), this is this vector starting from origin( is it like a position vector).

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions. It makes your question readable. Also if you have multiple questions, please ask them in different questions.

Comment: But to answer your question, what they do is the following: all vectors that can be moved into each other by translation (what you describe as a floating vector) are seen as the same vector. The position vector is just the vector that starts at the origin. Every vector can be moved to the origin so there is a position vector that corresponds with every class of floating vectors and they are all treated as "the same vector".

Comment: For a gradiënt vector one usually let's the gradiënt vector start in the point $(x,y)$. When calculating, one obviously uses the position vector representation.

Comment: So it it wrong or right to take gradient vector always starting at (0,0,0) if i want to?
And also now for directional derivatives wont the position of u(unit vector with which we take directional derivative with respect to) also decide the sliced portion of the graph? So in those cases, is u fixed?